# How I can draw several line graph in one single graph using amcharts

Tags: amcharts, jscharts

I am drawing a intractive graph using amcharts. I want to draw several line graphs in one single graph. But my code draw only one graph. When I add code for second line graph , it did not show anything due to error. How I can add second line graph in it. Here is .js file.

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
"type": "serial",
"theme": "light",
"marginTop":0,
"marginRight": 80,
"dataProvider": [{
    "D": "100",
    "value": 10
}, {
    "D": "200",
    "value": 20
}, {
    "D": "200",
    "value": 30
}, {
    "D": "400",
    "value": 40
}, {
    "D": "500",
    "value": 50

}],
"graphs": [{
    "id":"g1",
    "balloonText": "[[category]]<br><b><span style='font-size:14px;'>[[value]]</span></b>",
    "bullet": "round",
    "bulletSize": 8,         
    "lineColor": "#d1655d",
    "lineThickness": 2,
    "negativeLineColor": "#637bb6",
    "type": "smoothedLine",
    "valueField": "value"

}],

"chartCursor": {    /* required for  zoom effect */
    "cursorAlpha": 0,
    "valueLineEnabled":true,
    "valueLineBalloonEnabled":true,
    "valueLineAlpha":0.5,
    "fullWidth":true
},
/*show x axis values on graph*/
"categoryField": "D",


});

    chart.addListener("rendered", zoomChart);
    if(chart.zoomChart){
      chart.zoomChart();
 }

   function zoomChart(){
   chart.zoomToIndexes(Math.round(chart.dataProvider.length * 0.4),  Math.round(chart.dataProvider.length * 0.55));
 }
```

Comment: Jon, give me brief idea regarding my problem.

Comment: The code you posted is has both data and config for just one graph. Can you post your attempt at several graphs, so we can tell what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. If you want to plot more linegraphs in one single graph. Just add extra id' in "graph": and add  extra valueField inside that id. And add needed points in "dataProvider":. Similarly you can do this for more than 2 graphs by adding ids inside "graph":. And save it with .js extension.

```js
 var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
"type": "serial",
"theme": "light",
"marginTop":0,
"marginRight": 80,
"dataProvider": [{
    "D": "5",
    "value":0.30,
     "value1":0.5,

}, {
    "D": "10",
    "value": 0.29,
     "value1":0.27,

}, {
    "D": "15",
    "value": 0.28,
     "value1":0.20,

}, {
    "D": "20",
    "value": 0.27,
     "value1":0.32,

}, {
    "D": "25",
    "value": 0.26,
     "value1":0.25,


}],
"graphs": [{
    "id":"g1",
    "balloonText": "[[category]]<br><b><span style='font-size:14px;'>[[value]]</span></b>",
    "bullet": "round",
    "bulletSize": 8,         
    "lineColor": "#d1655d",
    "lineThickness": 2,
    "negativeLineColor": "#637bb6",
    "type": "smoothedLine",
     "title": "redpoint",
    "valueField": "value"
}, {

     "id":"g2",
     "balloonText": "[[category]]<br><b><span style='font-size:14px;>   [value]]</span></b>",  
     "bullet": "round",
     "bulletSize": 8,         
     "lineColor": "#20acd4",
     "lineThickness": 2,
     "negativeLineColor": "#637bb6",
     "type": "smoothedLine",
     "title": "bluepoint",
     "valueField": "value1"
     }],

    "chartCursor": {    /* required for  zoom effect */
    "cursorAlpha": 0,
    "valueLineEnabled":true,
    "valueLineBalloonEnabled":true,
    "valueLineAlpha":0.5,
    "fullWidth":true
},
  /*legend show points value on top*/
 "legend": {
 "useGraphSettings": true,
 "position": "top"
},
 /*show x axis values on graph*/
 "categoryField": "D",

 });
 chart.addListener("rendered", zoomChart);/*zoom effect*/
 if(chart.zoomChart){
 chart.zoomChart();
 }
 function zoomChart(){
 chart.zoomToIndexes(Math.round(chart.dataProvider.length * 0.4),   Math.round(chart.dataProvider.length * 0.55));
 }
```